# What is missing from this dhcp error?

Tags: fedora, dhcp

After starting the dhcpd service I got an error, but my console doesn't appear to be displaying the whole thing. I haven't set the dhcpd.conf file up yet, but I'm not sure where to start. Does anyone know what the full error is and what I have to add to the conf file to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Do you have any logs from dhcpd itself you could share? Some of those errors mentioned below from "server13 dhcpd[2437]" could have something to do with it. Unless you told dhcpd to log to a separate file, those messages are likely in /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Check and attach logs from journalctl -> `journalctl --unit dhcpd.service` or check system logs as @TheNH813 mentioned.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was the dhcp config file had absolutely nothing save for a couple comments and I just had to figure out how to do the config, which I managed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view the status message in a non-truncated format you could use:

```
systemctl status -l dhcpd
```